# Open source software to select the word under cursor and then insert it to MySQL?

Tags: open-source, mysql, vim

I mean when I’m editing or reading in vim I need to keep some words or sentences in MySQL database automatically only by hitting a shortcut key.

Comment: This question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13841/6834 might be related if you can import your data from a text file

Comment: It might be more easily doable with `emacs`  than with `vim`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your recommendation anyway. But so far as I know Vim is more popular than Emacs, which can be proved by searching Vim [Viml] and Emacs [Lisp] on GitHub and looking at the amont of results and stars of those listed on the top. Then I thought Vim users could gain more support from a larger community.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Vim script to do that:

https://github.com/eduOS/vocabook/blob/master/autoload/pyvocabook.vim

Set the database connection details at line 29.

License: MIT

Comment: I will definitively upvote this, as it is the best answer that can be hoped for by a question lacking so much detail. OP, please note that you will need to install Mysql and have it running; you will also need to know SQL in order to recode the fine example given to meet your needs.