# "Recording" clipboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is there a Windows 10 utility for "recording" the Clipboard to a (text-)file?

I looked Microsoft Store and there were hundreds of Clipboard-mangers and the likes, so I have no idea which one to pick.  I would prefer free (gratis) software, and without "buy-in-app" to activate essential functions..

What I want to do, is to use "Copy Link" to copy some links (for YouTube-videos) to the Clipboard, and then save each link to a file; so I end-up with a text-file containing links - one on each line.

So are there any programs that let me "record" everything I paste to the Clipboard - either one item at a time (and removing it from the Clipboard), or the whole "Clipboard-history" for a given time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool to append all copied text to a file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/tool-to-append-all-copied-text-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

**Ditto** is a very popular Clipboard Manager that should do what you want.

You can download it free from their site: **http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/**